# Why my button click event not run in asp.net 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net 4.0 my button click event not work,my html page first line is this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="DOCTORMINING.testPage" EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

and this very simple code behind:

```
Response.Write("okay");
```

but when i run the my application ,fire the button but code not run!,what happen?

my button html code is this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="نمایش" OnClick="Button1_Click1" Width="106px" />
```

i can't send my all html code,because very large.

Comment: I don't see a button in your code example. Please make sure your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is **complete**.

Comment: @Heinzi please review my question

Comment: And how `Button1_Click1` looks like in code behind file? You sure `Click1` is not a typo?

Comment: Your mcve is still not complete. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It doesn't matter that your code is very large: Just remove *everything* unrelated to the problem, until only the problem remains.

Answer (score -1):

Create a asp:button into HTML and in the HTML design view, double click to the button. Paste your code there.
If you aren't using asp:button use "onserverclick":

New Button